# Kafka Connect: bidirectional replication between 2 databases

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

My team needs to implement some kind of replication between 2 (or even more, but for now let's stay with 2) databases (PostgreSQL free edition). We decided to try Kafka Connect with Debezium PostgreSQL Source Connector and JDBC Sink connector. Here's example configuration scheme:

[image: Our configuration]

We want to make changes at both sides. And there's the problem: when data streams from Postgres-1 to Postgres-2 and Postgres-2 applies changes, Source Connector-2 receives these changes and streams them back to Postgres-1. Postgres-1 cannot apply these changes because it already has these records with primary keys. Then, if I understand correctly, in spite of not being applied on Postgres-1, changes will still be written to WAL of Postgres-1 and supplied to Source Connector-1 via pgoutput Postgres plugin. And we get an endless loop of changes that cannot be applied.

Questions:

1. is there any way to achieve this kind of replication using Kafka Connect or is it just a wrong usage of technology?
2. is there any way to put flags in Sink Connector and pass these flags to Postgres and somehow make Postgres send changes with flags to Source Connector for filtering?

Comment: Have you read this? https://debezium.io/blog/2017/09/25/streaming-to-another-database/

Comment: @OneCricketeer No, thanks for the link. But as I can see he tells about inserts in MySQL and getting changes in Postgres, but we also need to be able to make changes in both databases without loops. I mean, if you look at the general topology in the blog post, in our case there should be arrows back to MySQL and that's where the problem arise. With 1 direction everything is ok - I can make changes in PG-1 and get them in PG-2

Comment: @DistantBlue do you need to replicate a few tables or all tables ? setting up multi-master postgresql is realy tricky without using tools, BDR used to be opensource, now that is part of EDB you need to see: https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/bdr/latest/

Comment: you have a liste of tool offring multi-master replication https://www.postgresql.org/download/products/3-clusteringreplication/

Comment: @mshabou I need to replicate all tables. Thank you, i'll check out the links

Comment: My main point was that the post describes the flow of using Debezium and the JDBC sink. The destination shouldn't really matter, and you should also be able to setup a bidirectional connection by duplicating and flipping around the connector classes. I agrees that using a native/community Postgres specific solution might be better suited for this. Alternatively, CockroachDB will allow you to build a highly available, distributed, Postgres compatible database cluster, rather than just having replicas.

Comment: @DistantBlue, have you found any solution for such looped inserts/updates? In our team we need to make similar cross-cluster PG replication. And we are considering option with Debezium